# Rebex.Net.HttpRequest OAuth 2.0 Authorization Restful .Net Core

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, authorization

I have small client basically requests token from rest api and will do some calls over POST method.
For that purpose I need to do OAuth 2.0 authentication to the url. But I couldnt find how could I inject authorization data to the "request headers".
Header-Prefix = Bearer

Here is my code :

```cs
var token = "blablabalbal";
HttpRequest createExportJobRequest = httpRequestCreator.Create(exportJobUri);
createExportJobRequest.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
createExportJobRequest.Method = HttpMethod.Post.Method;
//createExportJobRequest.Headers.Add("bearer");
createExportJobRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
createTokenRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
createTokenRequest.Expect100Continue = false;
```

Please keep in mind I need solution only from `rebex.net.httprequest`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got too close and found solution need to use exaclty same line(5) at above code `Header.Add` :

```cs
createExportJobRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");
```